# Firstname initial and numeric style citing

Tags: biblatex, citing

When using numeric style the `\citet{key}` command  outputs `Lastname [n]`. I'd like this to output `Lastname F. [n]` where F is a `Firstname` initial. 
p.s.
Here is MWE code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldFont={DeJavu Serif Bold},
ItalicFont={DeJavu Serif Italic},
BoldItalicFont={DeJavu Serif BoldItalic}
]{DeJavu Serif}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baez/article,
    author       = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
    title        = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra {V}: 2-Groups},
    journaltitle = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
    date         = 2004,
    volume       = 12,
    pages        = {423-491},
    version      = 3,
    eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
    eprinttype   = {arxiv},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} with \texttt{eprint} and
        \texttt{eprinttype} fields. Note that the arXiv reference is
        transformed into a clickable link if \texttt{hyperref} support
        has been enabled.  Compare \texttt{baez\slash online}, which
        is the same item given as an \texttt{online} entry},
    hyphenation={english},
}
@article{another,
    author       = {Another,Author and One more, Author},
    title        = {Title},
    journaltitle = {Journal},
    date         = 2004,
    volume       = 12,
    pages        = {423-491},
    version      = 3,
    eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
    eprinttype   = {arxiv},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    hyphenation={english},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,
style=numeric,
isbn=true,
url=true,
defernumbers=false,
sorting=nyt, 
firstinits=true,
backend=biber,
language=auto,  
autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{another} \\
Some text \\
\citet{baez/article} \\
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have `Baez,J.C. and Lauda,A.D. [2]` italic shape is preferable :)
p.s.
It was noted to me in comments,that correct way to cite is `J.C. Baez and A.D. Lauda [2]` , but question remains :how to output name initials in numeric citation style

Comment: It would be far preferable to include an MWE here. That way, if the other post is edited, this question will still remain meaningful to future readers. If you rely on a link, the content may change if the content of the link is deleted or updated.

Comment: The example given there is rather more complex than this question suggests. Do you really want something which also satisfies desiderata not specified in this question? Because you are likely to get answers which don't take account of such desiderata, as the question is currently given.

Comment: The `\citet` command is designed for use in text. Normally - at least in English - it would not make sense to say `As Smith J. [18] proved in 1954...`.  If you used an initial you'd want `As J. Smith [18] proved in 1954...`. Do you want this for use with another language where the conventions are different?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but there is no 'J.' in output..for other language i an switch first-last/last-first right?

Comment: More general is how to output first names. When option will be firstinits=true, then output can be initials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134535/biblatex-authoryear-style-in-text-citations-display-first-name-initials-for-ce)

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio This is certainly not a duplicate of the question you suggested as a duplicate. Your question is concerned with unwanted initials or first names appearing, here the OP explicitly wants initials. He can't get initials all the time from the `uniquename` option.

Comment: Don't think, that after 5 month of initial post and answers marking post 'duplicate' is right

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio suggested post is how to turn off initials in author year style. This post is how to turn on initials in numeric style...I think those 2 are different

Comment: I have rolled back your edit about the duplicate question. That is better suited as a comment. Without context the comment just adds confusion to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

```
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}
```

would do the job. You get full names (if available) with `giveninits=false` and initials with `giveninits=true`.

---

With

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}<2
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

you will always get initials, except if full names are needed to disambiguate. (That only applies to `giveninits=false`, with `giveninits=true` only initials are available at all times.)
To enable that feature you need to set the `uniquename` option when loading.

See also [firstinits for citations only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266415/35864)

---

You can get a different order by replacing `family-given` by `given-family` in any of the above.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand this :"To enable that feature you need to set the labelname option when loading."

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili If you want to use that feature you will have to add `labelname` to the loading-time options, if you load `biblatex` with `\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}` you will need `\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, labelname]{biblatex}` instead. Or you just add `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelname}` to your preamble.

Comment: added after biblatex package call declarenameformat command above and after it `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelname}' and get error :Package keyval Error: labelname undefined. \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelname}

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Well this is pretty embarrassing: The option I'm talking about is actually called `uniquename` and not `labelname`. I'm really sorry. You can read up about it in the manual. Please replace all mentions of `labelname` above with `uniquename`.

Comment: 'firstinits=true,uniquename ` in option gives initials in both bibliography and in citation and `firstinits=false, uniquename' option full name in bibliography and initials in citation, but withiut 'uniquename' i get same

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili If you have `firstinits=true` you will always get initials only. If you have `firstinits=false` and `uniquename` you will get initials only if the disambiguation features allows for that. That is if you have no other author with the same last name and first name initial (note that this includes other versions of the same name: `Uthor, A.` and `Uthor, Anne` are two different names as far as `biblatex` is concerned and so you will get the full name, same for `Uthor, Anne E.` and `Uthor, Anne`). Without an example, I don't know what exactly is going on at your end.

Comment: got it now...yes it expands to fullname if two different citations give same output with initials...nice feature