# How to adjust verbose-like citation style to requirements of my department

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biblatex-dw, biblatex-chicago

I’m preparing my PhD thesis [social science] and I need to adjust style of footnotes and bibliography to the formal demands of my department [of one of the universities in Poland].

I need almost full citation in footnotes. So I started to use verbose

I started to use

> biblatex (with biber)

with

> style=verbose-inote-luh-ipw

as it is the closest style that I could find. But it still needs some improvements/modifications.

By using it i get something like this:
[image]

while I need something like this:

[image]

My desired format for footnotes and bibliography is:

1. For articles: Name of Author(s): *Title of article in italics and no quotation mark*. “Title of journal in quotation mark (without italics and no “[in:]” before it)” Year, vol. no.
2. For incollection: Name of Author(s): *Title of chapter in italics and no quotation mark*. [in:] *Title of book in italics*, Name of Editor(s) and after it (ed./eds. in parenthesis). City Year of publications (without comma in between)
3. For edited books: Name of author(s), (ed./eds. in parenthesis). *Title of book in italics*. City Year of publication (no comma in between)
4. For books: Only change that I need is that there would be no comma between City Year of publication

In sum, the abovementioned style has all the elements that I need but they order and formatting needs to be a little bit changed.

**MWE**

Main document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[totalwidth=180mm,totalheight=247mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote-luh-ipw,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Przypisy.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\footcite{Balmaceda.2008}.

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis\footcite{Aalto.2012c}.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris\footcite{Belyi.2015}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibliography (Przypisy.bib)

```
@incollection{Aalto.2012c,
 author = {Aalto, Pami and Dusseault, David and Kivinen, Markku and Kennedy, Michael D.},
 title = {{H}ow are {R}ussian energy policies formulated? {L}inking the actors and structures of energy policy},
 editor = {Aalto, Pami},
 booktitle = {{R}ussia's energy policies},
 year = {2012},
 address = {Cheltenham and Northampton, MA}
}


@article{Balmaceda.2008,
 author = {Balmaceda, Margarita Mercedes},
 year = {2008},
 title = {{C}orruption, {I}ntermediary {C}ompanies, and {E}nergy {S}ecurity: {L}ithuania's {L}essons for {C}entral and {E}astern {E}urope},
 volume = {55},
 number = {4},
 journal = {Problems of Post-Communism},
}


@book{Belyi.2015,
 year = {2015},
 title = {{S}tates and markets in hydrocarbon sectors},
 address = {Basingstoke and New York, NY},
 editor = {Belyi, Andrei V. and Talus, Kim}
}
```

In sum, the abovementioned style has all the elements that I need but they order and formatting needs to be a little bit changed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is always a bit difficult to answer questions that consist of so many wishes. We normally prefer to ask only one question per question. I'm also confident that you will find some of the pieces you need to get what you want have already been answered on this site.

Comment: Also note that sometimes it is easier to modify the standard styles (such as `verbose-inote`) than a customised and tailor-made style like `verbose-inote-luh-ipw`. `verbose-inote-luh-ipw` has not been updated since 2013 and `biblatex` has undergone a bit of change since then, you might experience some rough edges.

Comment: I thought that my question might be to specific (almost asking to prepare new style).
To be perfectly honest, I only invoked `verbose-inote-luh-ipw` because it had all the elements that I need, most importantly: abbreviations for journals: volume (polish – “t.”) and number (polish – “nr”)). Only problem that I had was with formatting (italics and quotations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `verbose-inote-luh-ipw` doesn't differ that much from `verbose-inote`, I decided to use the latter as basis. It is often nicer to modify the standard styles directly instead of the (sometimes highly-specific) custom styles.

Try (`filecontents` warning: the document will overwrite the `.bib` file with the same name)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Aalto.2012c,
 author    = {Aalto, Pami and Dusseault, David and Kivinen, Markku and Kennedy, Michael D.},
 title     = {{H}ow are {R}ussian energy policies formulated? {L}inking the actors and structures of energy policy},
 editor    = {Aalto, Pami},
 booktitle = {{R}ussia's energy policies},
 year      = {2012},
 address   = {Cheltenham and Northampton, MA},
}

@article{Balmaceda.2008,
 author  = {Balmaceda, Margarita Mercedes},
 year    = {2008},
 title   = {{C}orruption, {I}ntermediary {C}ompanies, and {E}nergy {S}ecurity: {L}ithuania's {L}essons for {C}entral and {E}astern {E}urope},
 volume  = {55},
 number  = {4},
 journal = {Problems of Post-Communism},
}

@book{Belyi.2015,
 year    = {2015},
 title   = {{S}tates and markets in hydrocarbon sectors},
 address = {Basingstoke and New York, NY},
 editor  = {Belyi, Andrei V. and Talus, Kim},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\labelnamepunct}

\newbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
       \bibstring{in}\addcolon}\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\newbibmacro*{puborginst+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{publisher}}
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{institution}}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{\usebibmacro{puborginst+location+date}{organization}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}


\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\footcite{Balmaceda.2008}.

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis\footcite{Aalto.2012c}.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris\footcite{Belyi.2015}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more question if i may: is there option to have in footnotes initials of name i.e. `M. M. Balmaceda` but full name and surname in bibliography i.e. `Balmaceda,   Margarita Mercedes`? I tried `firstinits=true` but it makes initials in both bibliography and footnotes.

Comment: @WojciechJędrzejewski Have a look at [firstinits for citations only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266415/35864).