# Different in-text citations and bibliography style for authors and editors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to show initials for authors and editors for in-text citations and full names for bibliography. Similar question and solution for authors only is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266415/firstinits-for-citations-only). Now I want the same functionality for editors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[book]{useeditor=false}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname-revinit}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}<2%
    \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
  \else
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartprefix}
          {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
  
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname-revinit}  

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{authoronly,
  author        = {Aniston, John},
  title         = {Make my day},
  location      = {London},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}

@book{authorandeditor,
  author        = {Clinton, Matthew},
  editor        = {Smakowski, Andrew AND Bronson, William},
  title         = {Good things},
  location      = {Torronto},
  date          = {2014},
  pagetotal     = {200},
}

@book{editoronly,
  editor        = {Lejba, Mose},
  title         = {Big brother},
  location      = {Boston},
  date          = {2020},
  pagetotal     = {300},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{authoronly}

ipsum \autocite{authorandeditor}

dolor\autocite{editoronly}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As a result now I have good order of given/family name everywhere. I have good style for authors. But I want editors appearing in `\printbibliography` to be also written with fullnames (but in reverse order than authors).
Result:
[image: editors full names]

Full editors names should be used in underlined places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `labelname-revinit` shown in the question exchanges given names for family names in some situations without telling `biblatex` about that. This results in unusual output like the comma between given name and family name, which is unusual for western names in natural "given family" order.

If you are roughly happy with what you are seeing, but would like to see given name initials in the citations and full given names in the bibliography, you may want to try the following, where we use the toggle `abx@bool@giveninits` to switch to initials in citations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[book]{useeditor=false}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{authoronly,
  author        = {Aniston, John},
  title         = {Make my day},
  location      = {London},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
@book{authorandeditor,
  author        = {Clinton, Matthew},
  editor        = {Smakowski, Andrew AND Bronson, William},
  title         = {Good things},
  location      = {Torronto},
  date          = {2014},
  pagetotal     = {200},
}
@book{editoronly,
  editor        = {Lejba, Mose},
  title         = {Big brother},
  location      = {Boston},
  date          = {2020},
  pagetotal     = {300},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{authoronly}

ipsum \autocite{authorandeditor}

dolor\autocite{editoronly}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aniston, John. Make my day. London, 1953. 100 pp. Big brother. Ed. by Mose Lejba. Boston, 2020. 300 pp. Clinton, Matthew. Good things. Ed. by Andrew Smakowski and William Bronson. Torronto, 2014. 200 pp. 1 J. Aniston. Make my day. London, 1953. 100 pp. 2 M. Clinton. Good things. Ed. by A. Smakowski and W. Bronson. Torronto, 2014. 200pp. 3 Big brother. Ed. by M. Lejba. Boston, 2020. 300 pp.]

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thanks! Unnecessary commas between the names you mention are removed with the command `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}`